# How to jump in inner tabs inside panel vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, settings, key-bindings

I'm trying to navigate inside `workbench.action.togglePanel`, but the ways I tried failed

[image: Guide here]

Does anyone know how to do it? similar to

```
{
    "key": "shift+l",
    "command": "workbench.action.nextEditor",
    "when": "!terminalFocus"
},
{
    "key": "shift+h",
    "command": "workbench.action.previousEditor",
    "when": "!terminalFocus"
},
```

but inside the panel

Thanks a lot.

I have tried this and a many other keybindings:

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+x",
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateLeft"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+x",
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateRight"
    },
```

Comment: Do you mean from your Terminal to your Explorer, for example?

Comment: Yeah but, without use ctrl + shift + e, ctrl + shift + x, else use ctrl l go to next panel, ctrl l next, next.. ctrl h previous

Answer (score 0):

Try these keybindings:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+x",
  "command": "workbench.action.nextPanelView"
},
{
  "key": "alt+y",
  "command": "workbench.action.previousPanelView"
}
```

Those will work wherever focus happens to be.  If you want to limit it to just when the panel already has focus use this `when` clause:

```json
"when": "panelFocus"
```